# Does NextFlow work for file-oriented cases?

Tags: nextflow

Reposting from here, hoping for clarification.

Thanks in advance.

---

I'm completely new to NextFlow and I'm puzzled that I can't do this simple thing, nor find documentation about it: I understand that NF is channel-oriented, but can it process file-oriented cases correctly?

I mean, suppose you have the usual case (see [this example](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/files/6961082/mydirs.nf.txt), rewrittent from another discussion):

- process A, creates file a
- process B, creates file b
- process C, does something with a+b and creates c (eg, joins a and b)

Now, I delete file a, I expect A and C to be re-executed, with C processing the new a and the existing b and recreating c.

That said,

- If I do it the regular way, ie, having files into the working dir, deleting working files is unacceptably difficult, since I have to rummage logs and dirs with hashed names until I find what I need. I expect to be able to just delete a or b (or, just `touch` them).
- I've tried `storeDir` and file dates are completely ignored, if a doesn't exist, but c does, A is re-executed but C isn't and the old c is kept.
- I don't think `publishDir` would work either, since I'd expect it to work like the first case (for the files remain in the working dir, except for `mode='move'`, which can only be used in a final step).

Am I missing something, or is it that NF isn't a good fit for file-oriented cases like the above?

Moreover, is there a way to run a pipeline only up to a given process (eg, to specify 'A')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nextflow [processes](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html) are  executed independently of each other and do not share a common (writable) state. The only way they can communicate is via asynchronous FIFO queues, called [channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channels).

The `path` input qualifier allows the handling of files in the process execution context. Nextflow will stage the file(s) in the process execution directory so they can be accessed by the script. Note that the `path` qualifier was introduced in version 19.10.0 as a drop-in replacement for the `file` qualifier and should be [preferred when using a recent version of Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-of-type-path).

In the code you've linked, the [storeDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#storedir) directive is used by each of your three processes. This is far from the 'the usual case' scenario. The directory specified by the storeDir directive is intended as a permanent cache for process results. Generally, these types of processes would have a large one-time cost that you would like to avoid paying again in future runs.

I refactored your example to show that when file 'a' is deleted from the working directory, processes A and C are indeed re-executed:

```
process A {

    output:
    path 'a.txt' into a_ch

    """
    seq 1 3 > a.txt
    """
}

process B {

    output:
    path 'b.txt' into b_ch

    """
    seq 4 5 > b.txt
    """
}

process C { 

    input:
    path a_txt from a_ch
    path b_txt from b_ch

    output:
    path 'c.txt'
   
    """
    cat "${a_txt}" "${b_txt}" > c.txt
    """
}
```

```
$ nextflow run test.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [agitated_payne] - revision: baea5be781
executor >  local (3)
[29/4bba82] process > A [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[d8/978a8d] process > B [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[14/999791] process > C [100%] 1 of 1 ✔

$ find . -type f -name '*.txt'
./work/14/9997911fcc4587f565822e4c8a238c/c.txt
./work/29/4bba8269b9337f28d20225d605b7cf/a.txt
./work/d8/978a8df7e7e1e5885007ebb0e2915d/b.txt

$ rm ./work/29/4bba8269b9337f28d20225d605b7cf/a.txt

$ nextflow run test.nf -resume
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [grave_albattani] - revision: baea5be781
executor >  local (2)
[7a/ec8636] process > A [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[d8/978a8d] process > B [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[2d/c2d34c] process > C [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
```

All that said and done, it's still not clear to my *why* you need to delete files from the working directory in the first place. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, I'll say avoid touching files in the working directory and instead use the [publishDir directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) to publish your process results, generally using the 'copy' mode i.e.: `publishDir './results', mode: 'copy'`. It won't suit all workflows, but it's a good default IMO. Then, if your want to for whatever reason, delete your files from the 'results' folder. When the workflow is resumed, any missing files will be copied across by Nextflow. This strategy will of course keep two copies of your published files on disk. But once you've finished with the workflow, you can simply turf the working directory and just keep the files in 'results' folder.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. my use of publishDir is an attempt to do what I want, which is keeping intermediate files out of hashed workdirs and being able to easily delete them when I see I need to rerun the pipeline from a given point (instead of from scratch, eg, because of a bug in a single script or an update of downloaded data). I call this the "usual case" since it's pretty standard in Snakemake or Make, I like NextFlow for other functions it has, but without this basic feature, I'm afraid I cannot use it for my workflows.

Comment: Moreover, `publishDir=copy` has two problems: 1) redundancy (which is relevant when you have 10Gb files) 2) if you delete the intermediate file in publishDir, NextFlow doesn't restart the pipeline from it, cause it looks at the original in the workdir and just copies it.

Comment: @zakmck just curious, why are you trying to keep 'intermediary' files out of the workdir? The working directory is the right place for these guys. If you leave these files alone, and you need to make changes to your workflow, then when you resume your workflow, Nextflow will automatically determine where to pick up from; see also the [cache directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cache). The directory specified using the publishDir directive should to be used to *keep* files you want.

Comment: Cause they're intermediate only from the point of view of the workflow, more in general, they're also part of the files I need to produce and put in configured download locations. I'd be fine with having them in the work dir, if I could avoid hashed names that are created at every run. That's way too messy for me and I'd prefer an option to reuse the cache that is created the first time and with my own names, just like other workflow systems work.

Comment: Also, to answer your last question: there's no way (AFAIK) to run a pipeline up to a certain process. But Nextflow pipelines are pretty trivial to hack to do what you want :-)  What's lacking in Nextflow is a way to auto-remove 'temporary' files to avoid having to *grow* and *shrink*. I.e. publishing (by copy) and then purging the workdir when complete. I think there's already an issue open for this.

Comment: Just read about the cache directive, thanks. It appears that NF doesn't directly understand the notion of: "run this process if its output doesn't exist or is older than its input". Apparently, it bases it all on process caches and achieves that semantics indirectly. From my POV, that's rather disappointing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last point. Nextflow will re-run a process if the process outputs don't exist in the working directory when using `-resume`. Nextflow automatically checks modification times and will localize/download files if the paths have a more recent modification time for example. Not sure if it will help, but you may like to try 'lenient' caching.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm still confused as to *why* the intermediary files need to be kept out of the working directory. Why can't they just stay there until you're finished with the workflow?

Comment: I mean, it seems that it always needs those hashed names before it can decide if to skip a process or not. The problem with those 'intermediate' files is that at some point, I need something like `/website/downloads/project1/v1/a` to be created (where `a` is intermediate), exactly in that place and with that path, without ugly paths like `d8/978a8d/a`. I could do it with `publishDir`, but that's redundant, confusing, messing. Maybe links from `/website/...` to the workdir could be acceptable, but apparently, NF doesn't support this direction (only workdir->extern).

Comment: I think using publishDir here is fine. I guess I don't know enough of the details to say why it'd be confusing or messy. If you need files (i.e. not links), then you'll need the 'copy' mode. The cost of data duplication is only a temporary issue IMO. In production, once the workflow is finished, all you'd need is to `rm -rf ./work`.

Comment: To me, it works in a poor way and copy mode requires much space with 10Gb files. If I become very keen of start using NF, I'll use this workaround, sticking to Snakemake for the time being. Many thanks for your comments.